# Problem with class generic: "Cannot assign [x] to `this.[y]` because property [z] is missing"

Tags: flowtype

I have a class generic who can be an instance of two different classes.
In the constructor, the class user must pass the type of instance to use, then, in a map object, i use this type to get the corresponding class.

Despite advanced typing, flow keep complaining that i can't store the instance because instance X is not compatible with instance Y.

[Please see this repro](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQgTgewO4GcJwBIEsXAXEASQDtcBDYgY2gF4oBvAHwCgo2oBqYCXBALigAKYgFcAtgCN0ASig0AfFFGT0zRgF8A3M2ahIUALIQx+ENl4ES5KrQYt2nMcf5DlUuLIVLx7tVp2UCKTAUAAWOHgEACrgEAZkYChyUADyEgBWEJTAAHQAZnAQEABeEIL0rOxOJgRsAoLl6gIUINICRjVmEaZWwBTU0gA0lWwSiKjoUPWNzcStAvDIaJjdlsH9ENLM6tLazJQANmQoSeaRIFAAPL0bMZACACQA0hAgKJd6EAh5Yasgd3EEih5IoKg4sOsbI8AKIHYwQYjAAEfWLfX4Wf6xeKJQZQG42AHyPYOQLBOAibL4QSfAT46gA2RghzsYDhFA5CHWajJNnnAHYlAAbU+AF1tA51NsdEA)

```js
type BrowserHistoryInstance = {|
    +foo: (number) => number
|};

type MemoryHistoryInstance = {|
    +bar: (number) => number
|};

const historyTypeMaps = Object.freeze({
    memory  : (({}: any): MemoryHistoryInstance),
    browser : (({}: any): BrowserHistoryInstance)
});

class History <InstanceType: $Keys<typeof historyTypeMaps>> {
    instance: $ElementType<typeof historyTypeMaps, InstanceType>;

    constructor(type: InstanceType) {
        this.instance = historyTypeMaps[type];
    }
}
```

---

**Error:**

```
this.instance = historyTypeMaps[type];
                ^ Cannot assign `historyTypeMaps[type]` to `this.instance` because property `memo` is missing 
                in `BrowserHistoryInstance` [1] but exists in `MemoryHistoryInstance` [2].

References:
        browser : (({}: any): BrowserHistoryInstance)
                              ^ [1]
        memory  : (({}: any): MemoryHistoryInstance),
                              ^ [2]
```